# Signing maven jar with Gradle 5.4.1 results in Could not set unknown property 'keyId'

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I'm trying to produce a maven signed jar but if I receive this exception

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not set unknown property 'keyId' for object of type org.gradle.plugins.signing.SigningExtension
```

**This is my build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id 'maven-publish'
    id 'signing'
}

apply from: 'gradle.properties'

group 'com.foo'
version '1.0.0'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // dependencies
}


task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    archiveClassifier = 'sources'
    from sourceSets.main.allJava
}

task javadocJar(type: Jar) {
    archiveClassifier = 'javadoc'
    from javadoc.destinationDir
}



publishing {
    publications {
        myLibrary(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java

            artifact sourcesJar
            artifact javadocJar
        }
    }

    repositories {
        maven {
            name = 'myRepo'
            url = "file://${buildDir}/repo"
        }
    }
}

signing.keyId='MY_KEY'
signing.password='MY_SECRET'
signing.secretKeyRingFile=/NOT_TO_PUBLISH/secret-keys.gpg


signing {
    sign publishing.publications.myLibrary
}
```

If I comment on the signing sections all works fine and my publications are generated.

Any helps would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/signing_plugin.html#sec:signatory_credentials) has them without quote marks:

> ```
> signing.keyId=24875D73
> signing.password=secret
> signing.secretKeyRingFile=/Users/me/.gnupg/secring.gpg
> ```

I'm sure you have, but have you tried without quote marks?

The documentation above also contains an alternate way of setting the values, do you get a different response?

> ```
>     allprojects {
>         ext."signing.keyId" = id
>         ext."signing.secretKeyRingFile" = file
>         ext."signing.password" = password
>     }
> ```

Additionally, are you using an up to date version of Gradle (so it properly supports the plugin)?

Comment: yeah, if I try this way I get "groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.Double.call() is applicable for argument types: (Integer) values: [73]"

Comment: Updated answer, try the other way of setting them?

Comment: with the second solution I receive "Could not get unknown property 'secret' for root project 'myLibrary' of type org.gradle.api.Project."